# check template name in django.test.TestCase

Tags: django, templates, testing

I am trying to write a tests for our simple application. Although, All the tests are running flawlessly, I am still wanting to check the template names that a view is rendering or redirecting to. What would be the best way to check what template does a view render.

Maybe something like:

```
self.assertTrue('test.html' in self.templates)
```

or

```
self.assertTrue(self.template.name, 'test.html')
```

How can this be acheived.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `assertTemplateUsed` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed)):

```
response = self.client.get('/url/')
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'test.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

From:
`response = self.client.get("/my/view/url")`

you can do

`self.assertEqual(response.templates[0].name, "expected_template.html")`

or:

`self.assertEqual(response.template[0].name, "expected_template.html")`

as 'template' and 'templates' are the same array.  Subsequent (non-zero) entries of this array list included or extended templates.